# How to change slowly background attributes in jquery?

Tags: jquery, attributes, background, jquery-animate

I want to animate the background, but it won't change with .animate!

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            "background": "-moz-radial-gradient(top, #fff, #cfcfcf)"
        }, "slow");
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            "background": "-moz-radial-gradient(top, #fff, #333)"
        }, "slow");
    });
});​
```

Comment: Did any other these answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would a simpler fade in / fade out meet your needs?

```
#div1{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:Black;
}​

$("#div1").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#FF0000").fadeIn(1000);
    });
});​
```

[Simple JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PzZNB/15/)

**EDIT**

```
#div1{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:Black;
    float:left;
}​

$('#div1').click(function (){
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#FF0000'}, 1000);
});​
```

See [new JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kT95d/16/) (uses jQuery UI). I believe that this will give you the effect you're looking for.

Comment: if i could change it without hiding it first.. that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) plugin to be able to use animating background

Comment: supported are only 'backgroundColor', 'borderBottomColor', 'borderLeftColor', 'borderRightColor', 'borderTopColor', 'color', 'outlineColor'

Answer (score 0):

The animate function only works with numberic units such as width, height, padding, margin, font-size...not with colors.

there are almost endless ways of doing this. Here is a list to check out:

http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations

http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/background-image-animation-with-jquery-jani

[**Have a look at this CSS3 solution for background colour animation**](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/581_cssTransitions/demos.html)

Just Google jQuery Backgorund image animation, but what they all have in common is that either a child element slides up and down or the background image position is being animated.

I advise you to stay away from the jQuery Color plugin as it sounds like a good idea when you look for things like this, but i think the community will agree with me that it is very buggy unless you go for the full UI library.

Comment: i cant do something with bgposition since i use css3 animations and the plugin only supports 'backgroundColor', 'borderBottomColor', 'borderLeftColor', 'borderRightColor', 'borderTopColor', 'color', 'outlineColor'

Comment: Then trying solving your problem using CSS transforms and not JavaScript. I think that way you will get better results. I added a CSS3 link for this

Answer (score 0):

You could position one div over another and fade the top one in and out. This will give you a smooth color transition.

**Updated example changes gradient on hover**
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/PzZNB/22/